# What is an efficient way to convert arrays/lists to dictionaries?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, dictionary

I'm trying to convert array information into a list in the most efficient (meaning the fastest) way possible.

I have a list that I call node_map, which I want to be the keys for the dictionary, then a 3D array of node_coordinates (node_coords_tmp) that I want to associate with the node_map.

Node_map looks like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Node_coords is reported back when printing initially as:

```
(<exodus.c_double_Array_8352100 object at 0x2c2d8c0>, <exodus.c_double_Array_8352100 object at 0x2c2d5f0>, <exodus.c_double_Array_8352100 object at 0x2c2d560>)
```

Initially I filled the dictionary like this:

```
    for ct,i in enumerate(node_map):
        node_coords[i] = [node_coords_tmp[0][ct],node_coords_tmp[1][ct],node_coords_tmp[2][ct]]
```

This did what I wanted, but was slower than I'd like for the size of the arrays I'm dealing with.  Is there a better way to do this using numpy or a different form?  Thanks.

Comment: How would you imagine populating a dictionary in less than O(n) time?  You have to iterate over each item.

Comment: It'll be O(n), but the coefficient can be significant depending on the specific n the OP is dealing with..

Comment: @dimo Not all algorythms with the same logarythmic estimation execute in exactly same time.

Comment: Of course not, but if your concern is related to the size of the input then you're asking about asymptotic complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a dict comprehension..

```
node_coords = { i: (node_coords_tmp[0][ct],
                    node_coords_tmp[1][ct],
                    node_coords_tmp[2][ct]) for ct, i in enumerate(node_map) }
```

Comment: Chad, thanks.  I had to go to python2.6 nomenclature (will this have any time penalty do you think, using 2.6 instead of 2.7 style dict comprehension?).  It was about 5% faster, which is a gain but I also may need to jump to some parallel stuff.  I had sped up some list-wise additions significantly by using np.add instead of sums over zipped list comprehension and was hoping I could find something similar here.  I may move to a new approach or shove through MPI.  Thanks again.

Comment: it should be about the same as using ```dict( (i,(...)) for ct, i in enumerate(...) )```